# non-breaking space not being displayed correctly in QTextEdit

Tags: qt4

`QTextEdit t; t.setHtml("&nbsp;");` displays a small 'a' with acute accent instead of a non-breaking space. This happens only on Windows not Linux or FreeBSD. 
What might be causing this? A bug in Windows/Qt? How can I fix this?

(Qt 4.5 on Windows Vista x64 pro. My locale is the default 'C'.)

Update: I have a feeling that this is bug in Qt/Windows (have already submitted a bug report). I have created a workaround but it's ugly and involves changing my formatting alogrithm and uses `<pre> </pre>` with CSS to produce the desired output.

Is there any simpler workaround?

Update: &8194; and &8195; both work as suggested by 'wcm'. Is it safe to assume that this will work for other users too?
`&nbsp;` not working is probably still a bug, but &8194; appears to be an acceptable workaround(?).

Update: Turns out I missed something important: `&nbsp;` in Qt/Windows renders incorrectly only with the particular monotype font that I was using called 'Terminal'. When I switched to 'Lucida Console' (or any other font for that matter) `&nbsp;` renders correctly! Man I wish I had noticed this earlier! Damn. So obviously there is a bug somewhere (most likely in Qt). But nevermind that, atleast for me using a different font has solved the problem.

Update: It's not a bug in Qt as I previously thought. 
To know the reason why `&nbsp;` is being rendered incorrectly please see Tewha's answer.

[SOLVED]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've mostly figured this out, but I thought I'd add the "why" of it. The Terminal font is based on code page 437, aka DOS-US. á is in position 160.

There aren't many fonts for code page 437. I think Terminal is the only TrueType one, in fact! At any rate, if you're not explicitly trying to display old school DOS graphics, you shouldn't be using Terminal.

What's code page 437 all about? It's "high ASCII", circa 1981. In addition to the usual 32-127 characters, it includes a few accented letters, box graphic characters to draw borders around things, some mathematical symbols and even symbols for the four suits of cards! But the world moved a different way, so aside from 32-127, even the glyphs that are usually available in other fonts aren't where you'd expect them to be. If you were running an old text-mode MSDOS program in a window, it would be using a code page 437 font.

See "[code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)" (Wikipedia) for more information.

Comment: Tewha, thanks for the clarification. 
It's perfectly clear now.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know much about the subject, so take this with a grain of salt, but have you tried one of the unicode variants like `&#160;` or `&#8194;` or `&#8195;` ?

I don't use QT myself, but I have had this problem with some documents generated using XML/XSLT.  Using `&#160;` took care of the issue for me.

Comment: I had tried &#160; before without success.

But, both &#8194; &#8195; work! Thanks a lot!

Is it safe to assume that &#8194/&#8195 will work on other computers too?

What do suppose is causing this behaviour? I don't really have a good understanding of i18n/unicode stuff and I am pretty sure I haven't messed with the locale or anything like that.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know about the 8194 or 8195 in other systems.  I pretty much work in a MS world :(  Sorry.

Comment: Does this mean I get the bounty?

Comment: Yes, but I am not seeing any option to select an answer or to commit the bounty (is it because of my low user points?).

Comment: wcm, will &819(4/5); work on other users(English speaking) computers running Windows too?

Comment: Again, I'm sorry I don't know that either.  My main work product is for intranet applications.  Maybe I don't deserve the bounty.  BTW, you should be able to check the checkbox underneath my number of up-votes.

Comment: Hi wcm, I found the problem (please see the update I added to my question). 

Strange, I don't see the checkbox underneath the up-votes. I remember seeing it before but for some reason it's not showing on this thread. Maybe the mods can select your answer on behalf. Or when the bounty expires tommorow the person with the highest up-votes will get the bounty, which will hopefully be you.

BTW, I still think you deserve the bounty, because you got my thought process going. :)

Comment: Actually I think the bounty expired today.  So it probably was given to the first person with one vote.  Oh well.  I'm glad you got your problem solved.  That's the important thing :o)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be: t.setHtml("<html>&nbsp;</html>");

```
t.setHtml("<html>&nbsp;</html>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't actually see anything in the docs ([here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/richtext-html-subset.html)) as to whether or not it even supports ampersand items. You might want to test some of the others like `"&amp;"` or `"&lt;"`.

There *is* mention of support for a `nobr` tag so you may be able to get a similar effect with (that's a space between those tags):

```
QTextEdit t;
t.setHtml("<nobr> </nobr>");
```

Comment: Nope, that too gives the same accented 'a'.

Comment: Also, I have tried different versions of Qt, from 4.3 to 4.5.1 and all have the same issue.

Comment: > You might want to test some of the others like "&amp;" or "&lt;".

Yeah, those work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this out on the Mac using Qt 4.5.0. The non-breaking space entity works perfectly fine along with the other entities. All I did was modify the source code in the MDI example project that ships with Qt 4.

MdiChild inherits QTextEdit, so in mdichild.cpp, I added the `setHtml()` call in the constructor:

[mdichild.cpp http://krsna.ca/dev/images/mdichild.png](http://krsna.ca/dev/images/mdichild.png)

That produced the following QTextEdit, complete with all of the entities, including the non-breaking spaces:

[MDI Screenshot http://krsna.ca/dev/images/mdi-screenshot.png](http://krsna.ca/dev/images/mdi-screenshot.png)

My guess is that it's a Windows bug.

Comment: Incidentally, I was wondering whether the problem occurs on Macosx but I don't have access to a Mac to test that. Thanks, for the input.

Yeah, looks like the bug is only in the Windows version. I have submitted a bug report, hope they fix it in a new release.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it under Windows XP SP3 x32 using Qt 4.5.0 and it worked as expected.
Not sure if it could be a problem with your Windows locales or a x64 specific bug although i doubt it.

Comment: hmm, odd. I did try it on XP SP2 (32-bit) too and it gave the same (incorrect) output.
i don't know, perhaps i am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing something like that to create whitespaces that work in QtextEdit (or QTextBrowser):

```
QString msg = "Some   Text   with  3   Whitespaces";
msg.replace(" ","&nbsp;");
```

All whitespaces will then be replaced by the html code &nbsp ; (hard-coded whitespace)
This worked very well for me.

EDIT: Sorry this only works with the following:

```
msg.prepend("<font></font>");
```

I don't understand why (the tag is closed so does it make sense?) maybe someone wants to explain it...